# How can I create a TextField that changes font and color on user input?

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, textfield, color-picker

I am fairly new to Flutter and writing in Dart language. I am trying to create a TextField that changes color and fontfamily on user input. So far I have a button that can create a new TextField. I have a Dialog created for font. I just don't know how to save the user input from font dialog and be able to link it to the TextField.

[Here is a photo with the TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYP1g.png)

[Here is where i can choose a font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThsJi.png)

Problem is I dont know how to link the font the user would choose to actually change the text font.

Can anyone help me out!

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() => runApp(TestApp());

TextField _textField1;
AlertDialog _fontPickerDialog;

class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestAppState createState() => _TestAppState();
}

class _TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test App',
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Center(
                //for the centered title in the appbar
                child: Text(
                  'TextField Test',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              ///textfield
              Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Click for TextField!'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          textField();
                        });
                      })),
              Container(
                child: _textField1,
              ),

              ///fontpicker
              Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Choose Font'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          fontPicker();
                        });
                      })),

              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: _fontPickerDialog,
              ),
            ])));
  }

  void textField() {
    _textField1 = TextField(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: "Type Here...",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void fontPicker() {
    _fontPickerDialog = AlertDialog(
        title: const Text(
          'Choose Font...',
        ),
        content: Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: ListView(children: [
              ListTile(
                  title: Text('Anton', style: GoogleFonts.getFont('Anton')),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _fontPickerDialog = null;
                    });
                  })
            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: There you go https://www.hotreloader.com/2020/05/dynamic-font-type-change-in-flutter.html ✌

Comment: I've got it working but there is a problem. When I click on the font I want to use, it doesn't change the font until I click the button to spawn a textfield. Seems like its not refreshing the textfield as soon as I click the font.

Comment: Could you just update your code in the question?

Comment: actually got it to work! Thank you so much for that link!

Comment: Good to know that✌

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a state variable `fontName` (maybe default to 'Roboto'), use it in your TextField style:

```
GoogleFonts.getFont(fontName, fontSize: 25)
```

and update it in `setState` in the font picker.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped alot!